# Add conditional field to table in Hive or Impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I have a massive table stored as parquet and I need to add columns based on conditions.
Is there a way to do that without having to recreate a new table in Hive or Impala?
Something like this?

```
ALTER TABLE xyz 
ADD COLUMN flag AS (CASE WHEN ... END)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that Hive or Impala support computed columns.  This type of calculation is often done using a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_xyz AS
     SELECT xyz.*,
            (CASE WHEN ... END) as flag
     FROM xyz;
```

You can then update the view at any time to adjust the logic or add new columns.

Comment: I'll give it a try!